# problema con función recursiva

Tags: java, recursión, árboles-binarios

tengo este código, que genera combinaciones de booleanos dentro de un arraylist llamado solución como si se tratara de un arbol binario pero sin nodos.
el problema es que al llamar la función start() solo entra el primero y no ambos,que puedo hacer?

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Backtacking{
    int nMatriz;
    Comparador comp;

    public Backtacking(int nMatriz ,Comparador comp){
        this.nMatriz=nMatriz;
        this.comp=comp;
}

public void start(int etapa, boolean combinacion, ArrayList<Boolean> solucion){
    solucion.add(etapa,combinacion);
    // if(comp.esFactible(solucion)){ // verifico si la nuevo solución es valida
        if(comp.estanTodos(solucion)){  // básicamente es un if(largoObjetivo==solucion.zise()); para obtener un arreglo de un largo determinado           
            comp.comprobar(solucion); // la compara y guarda [no importante]                              
        }else{ // de lo contrario lo agrando probando ambas posibilidades 
            start(etapa+1,false,solucion); //la que si es llamada
            start(etapa+1,true,solucion); //la que nunca es llamada por extraña razon
        }
    //}
}
}
```

comp es una instancia que tiene los métodos donde realizo las comprobaciones y la resolución de todos los vectores resultantes nada relevante con respecto al problema que me lleva aquí sobre la recursion.
dentro del Main lo llamo de esta forma;

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Comparador comp = new Comparador();
        Backtacking back = new Backtacking(nMatriz, comp);
        back.start(0,false,new ArrayList<Boolean>());
        back.start(0,true,new ArrayList<Boolean>());

    }
}
```

gran parte del código lo omito para evitar que este post sea tan grande por ejemplo como obtengo nMatriz entre otras variables

aquí un ejemplo de la salida de "solucion" que es un ArrayList; sale duplicada pero es por que en el Main llamo 2 veces el mismo método.

[image: ejemplo de salida]

en cada iterracion se logra ver como agrega un nuevo boolean a la lista, pero no se genera el arbol y no esta entrando en la segunda recursion de start()
mi pregunta es, es posible hacer recursion doble? y Como la puedo implementar en mi código?

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no se están llamando los dos? Sí se ejecutan ambos lados, pero estás haciendo un recorrido en profundidad: primero se ejecutará recursivamente `start(etapa+1,false,solucion);` y cuando se hayan ejecutado todos, se ejecutarán todas la llamadas a `start(etapa+1,true,solucion);`

Comment: @PabloLozano por que las llamadas de `start(etapa+1,true,solucion);` realmente no se esta realizando a comparacion de `start(etapa+1, true ,solucion);` y es lo que no logro comprender el por que?. concuerdo con lo que dices. deberia de realizarse la busqueda en profundidad. pero no entiendo el por que este no se esta realizando

Comment: La respuesta a tu pregunta es Sí, si se puede hacer que una funcion se llame dos veces. Aqui tienes un ejemplo básico que se ve que si funciona https://ideone.com/vQ6KSm
Tu problema debe estar quizá en el if o en que estas arrastrando valores que no deberias o algo similar.
Sin saber lo que hacen las funciones auxiliares tampoco podemos debuggar

Comment: puede influir que el metodo start() no sea estatico al momento de hacer recursividad?